# How to elegantly log inside a Doctrine2 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Consider the following situation. I have an entity that holds some information, let's say a news item. This news item contains comments.

In the news item entity, there is `calculateStatistics()` function, that returns some statistics derived from the news item entity, plus its comments. I used to have this calculate function inside a `NewsService`, but then found out a service wasn't needed because I only use information that is inside the entity.

Nowadays, the calculate function also does some sanity checking. I want to log negative results as a warning in my Monolog service. I still believe at this point it is valid to have this calculate function inside the entity, since no external information/service is needed. Is there an elegant way to support logging inside an entity?

Comment: Don't care too much about the sarcasm but ... the elegant way is not to log from the entity ;) Calculation why not, but not logging. Beware that Doctrine allows to load partial entities so that some properties can be NULL whereas they are valued in DB, so that calculation in the entity is even not a very good idea. Automating this process with an event seems to be the good way.

Comment: I think this is a good question. Right now the domain logic in our entities throws exceptions, which crashes our applications on unknown places. We could also return reasonable defaults, and let the entities log these occurrences for quite some of these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that handling logging inside Entity is a good idea, as entity should be as independent as possible and have no business logic inside. I would suggest doing it by [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html). Consider such configuration (I assume you're using `Doctrine` and want to perform logging while some doctrine event - but if not, you will only have to modify name of event which you listen to):

**Entity:**

```
class YourEntity implements StatisticInterface
{
    (...)
    public function calculateStatistics()
    {
        (...)
    }

}
```

**config.yml**

```
your_service.statistics_listener:
       class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\Entity\StatisticsEntityListener
       arguments: [@logger]
       tags:
           - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

`prePersist` is one of [many](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) possible events, just pick one that fits most

**StatisticsEntityListener**

```
class StatisticsEntityListener
{
    public function __construct(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof StatisticInterface) {
            //do whatever you like with your logger and entity
            $logger->log($entity->calculateStatistics());
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get nice separation of concerns and you're able to log info using your `Monolog`

Comment: Symfony enforces us not to put business in entities, but this principle is against OOP principles and other principles like Tell don't Ask. A model, if not a DTO, should be responsible for itself.